# Supabase session returns null after sign up

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, supabase

I want to direct users to the dashboard page from the register page after a user has signed up. I've created a `ProtectedRoute` component uses React-Router V6 that checks if a session exists, it will return the dashboard component since it is a protected route.

However, I'm encountering an issue. After calling `await supabase.signUp()` on the login page, I cannot access the `"/dashboard"`. I have checked in localStorage and can clearly see that a session has been added. I have tried logging the session in the console as you can see below as well as the `sess` (session) in the state. For the `sess`, I get null however, for the session, it returns a session object. For some reason, `setSession` doesn't seem to be working.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { supabase } from "../../supabaseClient";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const [sess, setSession] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
      console.log(sess);
      console.log(session);
    });

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session);
      console.log(sess);
      console.log(session);
    });
  }, []);

  return sess ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```